# How I do to load a leaflet map before the marker?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, android-jetpack-compose, location

im trying to create a map app in android compose with the current location, but the marker load before the map, and was crashing, I use a different method to fix it, but i see in an example code in the map insted the koltin file to fix it,  the next example:  var isOnline = false; how i can implement it to make the app simpler and efficient? Thanks!

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            (function () {

                // Objects
                var isOnline = false;
                var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 6);;

                // Generate tile layer url
                var tileLayerUrl = isOnline
                    ? 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                    : 'MapQuest/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg';

                // Set tile layer & add to map
                L.tileLayer(tileLayerUrl, {
                    minZoom : 6,
                    maxZoom : 8,
                    attribution: '&copy; <a target="_blank" href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                })
                .addTo(map);

                // Test marker
                L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
                    .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a <u>html</u> popup.");

            })();

        </script>
```

I ended doing this, the code can be more simple?

```
        update = { webView ->
            globalWebView = webView

            webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                    mapLoaded = true

                    if (mapLoaded) {
                        val locationViewModel = LocationViewModel()
                        if (locationViewModel.checkLocationPermission(context)) {
                            locationViewModel.getCurrentLocation(context) { lat, long ->
                                webView.loadUrl("javascript:getLocationAndPassToJavaScript($lat, $long)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (mapLoaded) {
                val locationViewModel = LocationViewModel()
                if (locationViewModel.checkLocationPermission(context)) {
                    locationViewModel.getCurrentLocation(context) { lat, long ->
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:getLocationAndPassToJavaScript($lat, $long)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```